# Do I need to sanitize input to file_exists?

Tags: php, sanitization

I can't seem to find a reference. I am assuming the **PHP** function `file_exists` uses system calls on linux and that these are safe for any string that does not contain a `\0` character, but I would like to be sure.

Does anyone have (preferably non-anecdotal) information regarding this? Is is vulnerable to injection if I don't check the strings first?

Comment: What kind of injection do you mean?

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov I mean essentially: "can anything unexpected happen?" My expectation being that the function will have no side effects.

Comment: You can only say if any code is safe from *known* attacks. I would *assume* it's safe, but there is no way of *knowing* it.
You can also [go down the rabbit hole of PHP source code and see for yourself](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/filestat.c#L1170). :)

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov wow that is a rabbit hole. It looks like it doesn't do anything magical other than splitting strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to protect against.

`file_exists` doesn't do any writing to disk, which means that the worst that can happen is that someone gains some information about your file system or the existence of files that you have.
In practice however, if you're doing something later on with the same file that was previously checked with `file_exists`, such as `include`ing it, you may wish to perform more stringent checks.

I'm assuming that you may be passing arbitrary values, possibly sourced from user input, into this function.
If that is the case, it somewhat depends on why you actually need to use `file_exists` in the first place.  In general, for any filesystem function that the user can pass values directly into, I'd try to filter out the string as much as possible.  This is really just being pedantic and on the safe side, and may be unnecessary in practice.

So, for example, if you only ever need to check the existence of a file in a single directory, you should probably strip out directory delimiters of all sorts.
From personal experience, I've only ever passed user input into a `file_exists` call for mapping to a controller file, in which case, I'd just strip out any non-alphanumeric + underscore character.

UPDATE: reading your comments recently added, no there aren't special characters as this isn't executed in a shell.  Even `\0` should be fine, at least on newer PHP versions (I believe older ones would cut the string before the `\0` when sent to underlying filesystem calls).

Comment: Okay, I guess to be more specific: I am checking to see if the file exists before looking in my database for metadata. The database access is sanitary, and the files I am looking for are not exectutable. I was only looking for other possible weakpoints.

Comment: So in that instance, there will be filesystem aliasing, eg 'file' is the same as './file', which may not be the case in your database.  Can't say whether this is a problem or not.  
I'm assuming that you'll be reading the metadata from the file if it exists?  In which case, the read may be a weak point if they can access a file you don't want them to see.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. After following Leonid Shevtsov's advice I must agree with your assessment. I will be careful with the metadata then.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to, because the user may enter something like :

`../../../somewhere_else/some_file` and  access a file that he is not allowed to access .

I suggest that you generate the absolute path of the file independently in your php code and just get the **file** name from user by [**basename()**](https://www.php.net/basename)

or exclude any input containing `../`  like :

```
$escaped_input = str_replace("../","",$input);
```

Comment: That is not really the type of thing I am worried about. Meaning: If that is the worst that can happen, then I don't really care. I am more worried about characters that have special meaning in some contexts, like `:`,`;`,`|`, etc

Comment: +1, thanks for the info anyway. Aliasing is something I would have had to worry about if I hadn't dealt with it already.